# C Programming char** for loop doesn't ever exit

Tags: c, pointers, char, maze

I am really new to programming in C, and I am stumped with the following problem:

- The user first inputs the number of columns and number of rows for their maze (in that order)
- They put in their "maze" to the console(an asterisk is a wall, a space represents a path, and  S and F represent Start and Finish) like this:

  ```
  ****S  ***
  *   ** ***
  ***    **F
  *** ***** 
  ***
  ```

I have stored the dimensions into int variables called height and width, and this is how my code looks right now:

```
    char **maze;
    bool **wasHere;
    int width, height;
    int startX, startY;
    int endX, endY;

    //Maze dimension one is the rows, maze dimension two is the 
    columns
    int main() {
       //Step one: initialize matrices
       scanf("%d%d\n", &width, &height);

       maze = malloc(height * sizeof(char*)); //dimension 1 = row#

       for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
              maze[i] = malloc((width + 2) * sizeof(char));
        }
/* From now on, maze[x][y] will refer to the (x,y) element of the maze,
 i.e., x-th row and y-th column in the maze */

//Set the wasHere boolean array to all false values
//I am trying to look at each row first, then move from left to right within that row
//then do the same for the rows below, until the row index is [height - 1]

//Step two: store the maze by reading in each row at a time
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
    //fgets reads in each row
    fgets(maze[i], width + 2, stdin);
    printf("\nStored row %d\n", i);
}
```

I have been testing it with a maze with 35 rows and 60 columns, but the for loop only runs up to i=15!
Any ideas???

Comment: What happens at i = 15?

Comment: Its working for me

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: malloc:  If the function failed to allocate the requested block of memory, a null pointer is returned. You should get used to check the return value.

Comment: tested with gcc, no problem seen, can't reproduce any strange behavior.

Comment: Help us help you: present a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  Be sure to follow the link if you have any uncertainty about what that is.  Not only will an MCVE give us what we need to know, but the exercise of creating one is useful in its own right.  Sometimes it even leads you to solving your own problem.

Comment: Thanks guys! For some reason it works when I compile with gcc, and there isn't any strange behavior. However, when I was working with it in XCode, it would get stuck on the loop... any ideas as to why this happens?